# webpack - TypeError: dep.getResourceIdentifier is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

Trying to mix under `laravel 5.6.7` using `laravel-mix 2.0.0` & `webpack 4.1.0`

`npm run dev`

getting this error on every run..
tried common work around,

- `deleted npm_modules folder`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm install`

still the same..

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> 0% compiling
>    10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...krish\node_modules\toastr\toastr.less
>    10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active
>    10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 active
>    10% building modules 2/3 modules 1 active ...\www\krish\resources\assets\js\app.js
>    10% building modules 2/5 modules 3 active ...\krish\resources\assets\sass\app.scss
>    10% building modules 3/6 modules 3 active ...sources\assets\less\adminlte-app.less
>    10% building modules 4/7 modules 3 active ...krish\node_modules\toastr\toastr.less
>    10% building modules 5/8 modules 3 active ...otstrap-less\bootstrap\bootstrap.less
>    10% building modules 6/8 modules 2 active ...sh\resources\assets\js\app-landing.js
>    10% building modules 6/9 modules 3 active ...krish\node_modules\toastr\toastr.less
>    10% building modules 6/11 modules 5 active ...\krish\resources\assets\sass\app.scss
>    10% building modules 6/12 modules 6 active ...sources\assets\less\adminlte-app.less
>    10% building modules 6/13 modules 7 active ...modules\style-loader\lib\addStyles.js
>    10% building modules 7/13 modules 6 active ...modules\style-loader\lib\addStyles.js
>    10% building modules 8/13 modules 5 active ...sources\assets\less\adminlte-app.less
>    10% building modules 8/14 modules 6 active ...de_modules\css-loader\lib\css-base.js
>    11% building modules 9/14 modules 5 active ...de_modules\css-loader\lib\css-base.js
>    11% building modules 10/14 modules 4 active ...de_modules\css-loader\lib\css-base.js
>    11% building modules 11/14 modules 3 active ...sources\assets\less\adminlte-app.less
>    11% building modules 11/15 modules 4 active ...node_modules\style-loader\lib\urls.js
>    11% building modules 11/16 modules 5 active ...h\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.common.js
>    11% building modules 12/16 modules 4 active ...h\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.common.js
>    11% building modules 13/16 modules 3 active ...h\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.common.js
>    11% building modules 14/16 modules 2 active ...sources\assets\less\adminlte-app.less**TypeError: dep.getResourceIdentifier is not a function**
>
> ```
> at addDependency (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:387:30)
> at iterationOfArrayCallback (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:78:3)
> at addDependenciesBlock (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:407:5)
> at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:418:4)
> at afterBuild (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:545:16)
> at _this.buildModule.err (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:591:11)
> at callback (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:342:35)
> at module.build.error (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:378:12)
> at handleParseResult (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:363:12)
> at doBuild.err (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:385:6)
> at runLoaders (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:264:12)
> at C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:370:3
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:211:10)
> at Array.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:4)
> at Storage.finished (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:16)
> at provider (C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:79:9)
> at C:\wamp\www\krish\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
> at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:532:3)
> ```
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! @ development: cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-05T19_05_05_252Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! @ dev: npm run development
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-05T19_05_05_702Z-debug.log
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**Package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.vue resources/assets/js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "acacha-forms": "^1.0.0",
    "admin-lte": "^2.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "bootstrap-less": "^3.3.8",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint": "^4.18.2",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "icheck": "^1.0.2",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "laravel-mix": "2.*",
    "less": "^3.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-loader": "^14.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-iconpicker": "^1.8.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "webpack": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Few more details.**
Node.js: `9.7.1`
npm: `5.7.1`
webpack: `4.1.0`
OS: `Win10 32bit`
Except bootstrap, all packages are up-to-date.

Ref: [There is no html-webpack-plugin as mentioned here..](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6064#issuecomment-349139146)

Comment: check this link  https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1314

Comment: @krishankTripathi What does this issue have to do with the issue mentioned above?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like Laravel Mix is not yet compatible with Webpack 4.
The only thing I found we can do for now is to switch back to Webpack `^3.11.0`. (Do this by changing the version in your package.json).

Here is an open issue about this problem: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6675

Comment: It's 2020 and this is still a problem. Can't get vue components tested.